# how to add a horizontal line after each heading in an HTML with only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a horizontal line after each heading without using `<hr>`? I only want to add something inside `<style> </style>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add a line after a heading IS to use CSS not a `<hr/>` element. note that H elements are block level elements (unless you are styling them to be inline or are using display: flex on the parent container, so the border-bottom will extend the full width of thecontainer.

This can be applied individually to any h element - or to them all by combining all h elements into a single style declaration.

```css
h1 {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply:

```
h1::after{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```